# Simple jQuery UI Tooltip with no title attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm trying to work with jQuery UI Tooltip and I think I may be missing something.

I want the simplest possible tooltip to show up without specifying the title property.

I believe I should be able to call this pretty much anywhere in my javascript:

```
$('#ContactName').tooltip({ content: 'Hey, look!' }).tooltip('open');
```

This is not working. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I should mention that #ContactName is an input[type=text], and it is in a jQuery UI dialog.

EDIT 2: Okay this worked. I don't really understand why, though.

```
$($('#ContactName').parent()).tooltip({
    items: '#ContactName',
    content: 'Hey, look!'
});
```

It works on hover. Is there anyway that I can, in the same code, make it open immediately?

EDIT 3: This is what I ended up with:

```
            $($('#ContactName')).tooltip({
                items: '#ContactName',
                content: $(this).text(),
                position: {
                    my: 'left+15',
                    at: 'right center'
                },
                tooltipClass: 'ui-state-error'
            }).tooltip("open");
```

Comment: See also: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-tooltips-require-a-title-tag

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you set the `content` option you may also need to specify the `items` option.

See their [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) documentation and this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vCw9X/)

```
<span id="ContactName">Test</span>

$("#ContactName").tooltip({
    items: "span",
    content: "Awesome title!"
}).tooltip("open");
```

Comment: Why does it have to be bound to the container?

Comment: @JoshYoung, see update. It doesn't need to be, but you do have to bind it to something and then tell it specifically what items to look at. I'm not sure how to reference `this` in the options element, but you can just use the element selector.

Comment: That is working. Is there any way I can make it open immediately?

Comment: @JoshYoung, call `open` after initializing the tooltip. See update.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hacky but when `items` doesn't work for you (let's say you are doing for multiple selectors at once) you can also set title on the fly:

```
$($('#ContactName')).
        attr('title', '').
        tooltip({
            content: $(this).text(),
            position: {
                my: 'left+15',
                at: 'right center'
            },
            tooltipClass: 'ui-state-error'
        }).tooltip("open");
```

Comment: Right value for `content` should be : `function() { return $(this).text(); }`. `items` should be set also.